# Passing dynamic arguments to usePrepareContractWrite in Wagmi

Tags: wagmi

Working with usePrepareContractWrite  Dealing with the logical flow

```
const { config: contractWriteConfig } = usePrepareContractWrite({
    ...contractConfig,
    functionName: 'mint',
    args: [numToMint],
    overrides: {
        value: ethers.utils.parseEther(payment),  //how do I dynamically change this number on the fly to string
      },
  });
```

```
const {
    data: mintData,
    write: mintBee,
    isLoading: isMintLoading,
    isSuccess: isMintStarted,
    error: mintError,
  } = useContractWrite(contractWriteConfig);
```

In short I'm using a handle event for the number to mint.  Before I could multiply the numToMint by the cost amount and convert it to string in another function.  Now with usePrepareContractWrite()  I'm unsure how to approach this as I can't pass arguments to the "mintBee" write function.  Any examples are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Basically, @deepak-sharma has got some things right but his `useEffect` will trigger an infinite loop and we can also make it a bit better by using a [useDebounce](https://usehooks-ts.com/react-hook/use-debounce) (as recommended in [wagmi's docs](https://wagmi.sh/examples/contract-write-dynamic#step-5-add-a-debounce-to-the-input-value)).

```js
import * as React from 'react'
import { ethers } from 'ethers'
import { usePrepareContractWrite, useContractWrite } from 'wagmi'

import { useDebounce } from './useDebounce'
import contractConfig from './contract-config'

export default function MintComponent() {
  const [numToMint, setNumToMint] = React.useState(0)
  const [payment, setPayment] = React.useState(0)

  const debouncedNumToMint = useDebounce(numToMint)
  const debouncedPayment = useDebounce(payment)

  const { config: contractWriteConfig } = usePrepareContractWrite({
    ...contractConfig,
    functionName: 'mint',
    args: [debouncedNumToMint],
    overrides: {
      value: ethers.utils.parseEther(debouncedPayment.toString()),
    },
  })

  const { write: mintBee } = useContractWrite(contractWriteConfig)

  return (
    <form
      onSubmit={e => {
        e.preventDefault()
        mintBee?.()
      }}>
      <label htmlFor='payment'>Payment</label>
      <input
        id='payment'
        type='number'
        onChange={e => setPayment(e.target.value)}
        value={debouncedPayment}
      />
      <label htmlFor='numToMint'>Num to mint</label>
      <input
        id='numToMint'
        type='number'
        onChange={e => setNumToMint(e.target.value)}
        value={debouncedNumToMint}
      />

      <button disabled={!mintBee}>Mint</button>
    </form>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work because change in state will trigger the hook to rerender.

```
const [numToMint, setNumToMint] = React.useState()

const { config: contractWriteConfig } = usePrepareContractWrite({
    ...contractConfig,
    functionName: 'mint',
    args: [numToMint],
    overrides: {
        value: ethers.utils.parseEther(payment)
      },
  });

const {
    data: mintData,
    write: mintBee,
    isLoading: isMintLoading,
    isSuccess: isMintStarted,
    error: mintError,
  } = useContractWrite(contractWriteConfig);

React.useEffect(() =>{
    setNumToMint((numToMint * costAmount).toString())
},[numToMint])
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the **refetch** method from **usePrepareContractWrite** and this was enough for me to get the last value in my states.

```
const { config: configRemove, refetch: refetchRemove } =
usePrepareContractWrite({
  address: contractAddress,
  abi: abi.abi,
  functionName: "removeProject",
  from: walletClient?.account?.address,
  args: [removeId.current || 0],
});
```

I used useRef instead of useState.

You can see my production code here: https://github.com/paulobordignon/portfolio/blob/33ff09448b319065e67db4a5dd4bab792bb8b71d/src/components/organisms/Admin/Admin.tsx